# How to respond to an HTTP request before executing my program logic in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm building a Slack chat bot. Once the user types a message, Slack sends the message to my back-end application on GAE. Slack needs me to respond back with a HTTP 200 within 3 seconds (otherwise it keeps sending the message back to my back-end which creates a mess because my app thinks it a new message).

The problem is my app sometimes (depending on the message) needs more than 3 sec to process the incoming message.  How can I immediately respond to the incoming message with HTTP 200 and then process the message separately at my own pace.

Here is my current program structure:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def webhook():
   slack_incomming_message= request.get_json() #Get the incoming message from Slack

   # do a bunch of stuff that takes more than 3 seconds

   return make_response ('', 200) # respond back to slack with HTTP 200
```

Ideally, I would want to do something like the below where I respond with HTTP 200 first then execute my program. Obviously my suggestion below wont work as nothing after the "return make response" will get executed. But Im wondering how can I accomplish something that has the same effect where I send HTTP 200 and then run my program?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def webhook():
   #Get the incoming message from Slack
   slack_incomming_message= request.get_json()

   # respond immediately back to slack with HTTP 200
   return make_response ('', 200)

   # then go do a bunch of stuff that takes more than 3 seconds
```

Comment: Try an async library like http://www.celeryproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

You may try using non blocking thread, like this:

```
import threading

thread_lock = threading.Lock()
threads = []

    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

    def webhook():
       slack_incomming_message= request.get_json()
       thread = threading.Thread(target=bunch_of_stuff(), args = (arg1, arg2))
       thread.deamon = True
       thread.start()
       with dataLock:  # lock appending operation to get rid of simultaneous object sharing
           thread.append(thread)  # or you may use Queue instead

       return make_response ('', 200)
```

Perhaps using [Celery](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Celery/) or [rq](https://pypi.org/project/rq/) would be a better option.

Comment: I will have a look at Celery. One way Im working around this now is by using Google Sub/Pub service which can queue up the messages allowing me to respond to them at my own pace. But I will research Celery.